Checking to see if a string contains another string and moving relevant numbers to a corresponding position on another sheet based on that string
Im in construction trying write something to track material inventory from vendors based on material type and moving that quantity from one sheet to another. The problem is that the material name is slightly different on one sheet versus another. For example if i were trying to track "siding", my sheet would just say "siding" while the other would have "veriform siding". I want a working code that would recognize the word "siding" in "veriform siding" and know to move over any amount of veriform siding from the vendor sheet and add it under siding in my sheet. I'm hoping someone can help my find a way to use InStr do to what I need.
Right now my code only works if the strings are exact.
Sub simple2()

Dim i As Integer

Dim u As Integer

yarray = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(14, 1).CurrentRegion

zarray = Worksheets("Walk").Cells(5, 1).CurrentRegion


    For d = 14 To UBound(yarray)
       Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(d, 1).Value = Trim(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(d, 1).Value)
    Next
    

    For q = 5 To UBound(zarray)
       Worksheets("Walk").Cells(q, 1).Value = Trim(Worksheets("Walk").Cells(q, 1).Value)
    Next


For i = 14 To 30

If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value >= 0 Then

    For u = 5 To 39
    
        If Worksheets("Walk").Cells(u, 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value Then
        
        Worksheets("Walk").Cells(u, 2) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value
        
        End If
        
     Next
    
End If

Next
End Sub



How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator

Does "to move over any amount of veriform siding" mean there may be multiple cells that contain siding and you want to return the sum of the corresponding values from column C of Sheet1 in column B of Walk? Also, which sheet has the shorter names?

VBA sounds a bit like an overkill.
You can use a formula like Searh (not case-sensitive) of Find (case-sensitive). Look for "siding" a every cell of the sheet you need and if the condition is met copy the value you need with IF function.
If you need to sum values based on a condition you can use something like SUMIF function.
Without seeing your file its pretty hard to say which tool is better.

So I actually found a way to solve my issue, pretty much I used an inStr function to identify a string match and if there is any positive value for return position it moves the number data over for that material.
For u = 5 To 39
If InStr(Worksheets("Walk").Cells(u, 1).Value, Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value) >= 1 Then
Worksheets("Walk").Cells(u, 2) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value
End If
Next

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
